# PyQt4 not installing on Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, pyqt4

I am using an older code which uses extensive PyQt4 modules.

Rather than rewrite it, I am using an older version of Python 2.7 and installing PyQt4. I saw people say to use pip install PyQt4‑4.11.4‑cp27‑cp27m‑win32.whl (depending on what version of Python was used).

However, I keep getting the error:

> PyQt4-4.11.4-cp27-cp27m-win32.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.

How can I install it?

Comment: What pip command did you type exactly? What is your operating system?

Comment: pip install PyQt4-4.11.4-cp27-cp27m-win32.whl and windows

Answer (score 0):

try to install this.
download http://sourceforge.net/projects/pyqt/files/PyQt4/PyQt-4.11.4/PyQt4-4.11.4-gpl-Py2.7-Qt4.8.7-x32.exe

Comment: Installed it, what should I enter in the terminal?